# What is an efficient way to get a diff of two MySQL tables based on several columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, workflow

I'm trying to reconcile the data that I already have (an inventory list) with a daily update, which is a table with the same layout; all I need are the rows that have differences in any of the four fields from the current table (differences in other fields aren't considered.)

What I'm doing now is this:

```
insert into diff
    select * from new n
    where concat(n.distrib_pn, n.available_total, n.cost, n.map) not in
    (select concat(c.distrib_pn, c.available_total, c.cost, c.map) from current c);
```

It's very slow: ~35 seconds for two files of ~7,000 rows.`new`, `current`, and `diff` tables are indexed on `distrib_pn`. I've also tried doing this without using `concat()`, but couldn't figure out the syntax.

Comment: Ultimately, what are you trying to achieve, are you planning to update the current table with the differences from the new table? If so, you're going about it wrong, forget your diff table and google how to upsert in mysql. e.g. http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/02/21/flexible-insert-and-update-in-mysql/

Comment: Thanks, @RelativePHPNewbie - that sounds like exactly the kind of thing I'm looking for, really appreciated! I'll explore this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use join query to perform this action:

```
insert into diff
    select n.* from new n inner join current c on 
          n.distrib_pn != c.distrib_pn and
          n.available_total != c.available_total and
          n.cost != c.cost and
          n.map != c.map;
```

Comment: Hi, Jim - that doesn't work (much like my original try at doing a multi-field join.) I've even tried adding commas between the field comparisons and parens around the list; I get the same error every time:


`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'n.available_total != c.available_total n.cost != c.cost n.ma' at line 1`

Comment: Update: adding 'OR' in between the comparisons made it work, but takes much more time (I launched it two minutes ago, and it's still running.)

Comment: Instead of OR provide AND. It will work. Using join is the fastest way to optimize performance. May be you have lots of data in the table which makes your performance slow

Comment: I just tried it with 'AND'; it produced 24,378,000 records in 39.94 seconds (I aborted the query and re-ran it with 'SELECT COUNT(*)' to see.) I'm afraid it doesn't work at all.

I have 7389 records in 'new' and 7400 in 'current', so these are not big data sets.

Comment: Based on the count, the time taken is very less. So this is the efficient way. We can use WHERE condition as well, but it takes more time than join query

Comment: Jim, the difference between two sets of ~7400 records **cannot be** 24+ million records. Your answer is factually wrong, and becoming more wrong with every excuse. I suggest you stop digging.

Answer (score 0):

This will be faster, but not necessarily fast.

```
select n.*
from new n left join current c 
on concat(n.distrib_pn, n.available_total, n.cost, n.map) 
= concat(c.distrib_pn, c.available_total, c.cost, c.map)
where c.distrib_pn is null
```

What makes it faster is that you are not using `not in`.  Joining on a function result will slow things down.  However, depending on what your query is supposed to accomplish, it might be the only way.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't seem to make any significant difference (31.29 seconds vs. the previous 33.58.) Thanks for giving it a shot, though.